# change YuvToRgbConverter to rotate and scale based on CameraX

Tags: android, renderscript, android-camerax

I was able to successfully integrate YUV to RGB converter that converts Image to Bitmap on android.
But this conversion does not take into account camera orientation or resize.

I tried adding ScriptIntrinsicResize with no success.

Is there a way to extend it using standard ScriptIntrinsic implementations.

https://github.com/xizhang/camerax-gpuimage/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/appinmotion/gpuimage/YuvToRgbConverter.kt